# Numerical calculation using case_when

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, case-when

I have the following type of data
`df <- data.frame(Group=rep(c("A", "B"), 3), var1 = rnorm(6)*100)`

I want to create a new variable by dividing var1 with a number specific for each group.

I tried, `df %>% mutate(var2 = case_when(Group == "A" ~ var1/100, Group == "B" ~ var1/120))`
Any suggestion to work with numerical calculations using `case_when` or any alternative `apply` family of functions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your data is large I would suggest that you create a mapping table which contains the factor for each group:

```
mapping_factor <- tibble(Group = c("A", "B"), f = c(100, 120))
```

Then you can simply join the mapping table and divide afterwards:

```
df %>% left_join(mapping_factor, by = "Group") %>% 
  mutate(var2 = var1 / f)
```

If your data is not that big nad you do not have many different `Group` attributes you can work with `case_when`:

```
df %>% mutate(var2 = var1 / case_when(Group == "A" ~ 100, 
                                      Group == "B" ~  120))
```

Comment: Both solution works great - accepted answer! I have a larger dataset with multiple groups.